# Activate workspace on user login

Tags: 22.04, workspaces

In Ubuntu 22.04 when a user logs in, he sees the workspace selector and has to click on a particular workspace to start. I don't use multiple workspaces and always have only one of them, so the workspace selection experience makes no sense for me. How do I disable the workspace selection on log in and have my single workspace activated by default?

Workspace selection at login:

[image: workspace selection at login]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't comment on Arjun's answer, but I would like to add my two cents to it. In the **Just Perfection** extension, under the **Behavior** section, there is and option labeled **Startup Status**. I switched it to **Desktop** and it's using that option by default at login. I hope that solves it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an extension called Just Perfection.
In order to install it, type the following commands into the Terminal.

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions
```

Then you can install the gnome extension manager by using the command

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager
```

Open Extension Manager, click on Browse and then search **Just Perfection** in the search box and install the extension.

After installing it log out of the system and on next login search for extensions in apps and open it.
You'll find Just perfection extension under Manually Installed section in there, click on settings under the extension name, the extension settings pop up, now click visibility on bottom and disable the option called **Workspace Popup**.

That should do. Hope it heps!!

Comment: No, it did not work.